# Can information schema table rows value be 0 for non empty table?

Tags: mysql, sql, innodb

As stated in [mysql information schema](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-infoschema-excerpt/5.7/en/information-schema-tables-table.html) about TABLE_ROWS

> For other storage engines, such as InnoDB, this value is an approximation, and may vary from the actual value by as much as 40% to 50%. In such cases, use SELECT COUNT(*) to obtain an accurate count.

My question is, is it possible that `TABLE_ROWS will be 0` for non-empty table?

I've run multiple tests, and the value was always updated to `0` or `bigger than 0` depending on the action that I took (insert to empty table or delete all). But is anyone able to tell that I can rely on this behavior?

Comment: When you just want to check if there is a record, you can always do `SELECT 1 FROM tablename LIMIT 1`, which performs better than `SELECT count(*) FROM tablename`. Can you add some info on what you want to do with TABLE_ROWS  from the information_schema ?

Comment: I know that I can perform other queries to check. The point is, that INFORMATION_SCHEMA can be used to write fast and simple sql, to check if there is table with no data in the database, and that is actually purpose of the question. If I won't be sure about behavior i asked, then I will stick to the procedure that execute the query you mentioned, on every table in database.

Comment: In that case, the answer is Yes, that will be possible.  Reason one: 1) this value is an approximation.   2) I do have a table on my local system for which TABLE_ROWS=0, but that (InnoDB-)_table does actually contain a record.   (And after `ANALYZE TABLE tablename`, the value for TABLE_ROWS changes, but will still be an _approximation_ of the real value  )

Comment: Are you using MySQL 8.0? The statistics in the information_schema are cached by default, and update only every 24 hours, even if you use `ANALYZE TABLE`. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_information_schema_stats_expiry

Comment: Was `ALTER` the last thing done to the table?  If so, what variant of `ALTER`?

Comment: @BillKarwin Are you sure about that statement? The page you linked clearly states 
`To update cached values at any time for a given table, use ANALYZE TABLE. `
Also I believe that would be really confusing behavior, if `ANALYZE TABLE`, didn't work that way.

Comment: @RickJames Is that question towards me? I didn't do any `ALTER`. The 'test' I've done were simply `INSERT`, `DELETE`.

Comment: Well, you can try an experiment. Try using `ANALYZE TABLE` and see if it updates the table stats in INFORMATION_SCHEMA. If it doesn't, then try setting `information_schema_stats_expiry=0` and then `ANALYZE TABLE` and check the stats again.